# Can I template user-defined literals?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, user-defined-literals

Suppose I have some class:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  const T* x_;
public:
  Foo(const T* str) : x_{str} {}
};
```

and I provide some user-defined literals that create a `Foo` object:

```
Foo<char> operator"" _foo(const char* str, std::size_t) {
  return Foo<char>{str};
}

Foo<wchar_t> operator"" _foo(const wchar_t* str, std::size_t) {
  return Foo<wchar_t>{str};
}

// etc. for char16_t and char32_t.
```

My question is this: why can I not template these and save having to rewrite code?

```
template <typename T>
Foo<T> operator"" _foo(const T* str, std::size_t) {
  return Foo<T>{str};
}
```

gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) and 7.0.0 (compiled myself) report:

```
error: ‘Foo<T> operator""_foo(const T*, std::size_t)’ has invalid argument list
Foo<T> operator"" _foo(const T* str, std::size_t) {
                                                ^
```

The error message seems to be clear enough, but I don't see a reason why I shouldn't be allowed to do this in principle; so, am I doing this incorrectly, or is this genuinely not allowed?

Comment: 2.14.8/3 suggests template user-defined operator literals are valid. Per /5, your code would seem, to me, to be correct. Your compiler isn't picking up the operator template specialisation up as (specifically) a user-defined _string_ literal operator, and my template fu isn't good to enough to figure out whether this is a bug, or a consequence of lookup rules.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess [over.literal] is more appropriate here. It seems that a function template that involves a literal operator id must adhere to a fixed declaration (more or less `template <char...> double operator "" _x()`). No other form is allowed apparently.

Comment: @skypjack: The wording makes me suggest trying it with an explicit instantiation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I thought the same thing about my compiler (I think!). Anyway, trying to also put in an explicit instantiation gave the error: `error: template-id 'operator""_foo<>' for 'Foo<char> operator""_foo(const char*, std::size_t)' does not match any template declaration`. Which, again, leaves me with: is this my compiler not picking up on my template declaration, or is it just not allowed? I guess it must be the latter, although I don't understand why...

Comment: @Zorawar: The answer below is very good.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I know :) What I meant was: "I don't understand why _in principle_..." Maybe it's just not useful enough to consider adding when you're already restricting the arguments?

Comment: @Zorawar: Could be. I'd wager just nobody considered it.

Comment: @Zorawar _Why in principle_ is something you should ask to the working group or similar. ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal):

> If the literal operator is a template, it must have an empty parameter list and can have only one template parameter, which must be a non-type template parameter pack with element type char

In other terms, the declaration of a literal operator template should be:

```
template <char...> double operator "" _x();
```

That is not your case.

---

I'm not a language-lawyer, but I guess the section of the standard that is relevant for your case is [[over.literal]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal) (link to the working draft).

An excerpt from [[over.literal]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal#2) follows:

> A function template declared with a literal-operator-id is a literal operator template.

Below [[over.literal]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal#5) is quoted:

> The declaration of a literal operator template shall have an empty parameter-declaration-clause and its template-parameter-list shall have a single template-parameter that is a non-type template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]) with element type char.

It seems to me that declarations similar to the one in the question are explicitly disallowed by the standard.
More in general, a function template that declares a literal operator must adhere strictly to the given pattern.

---

> am I doing this incorrectly, or is this genuinely not allowed?

I would say that's *genuinely not allowed*.

Anyway, you can still use a template function if you have complex logic that you don't want to repeat in each operator:

```
template<typename T>
Foo<T> create(const T *str) {
    // your logic...
    return Foo<T>{str};
}

Foo<char> operator"" _foo(const char *str, std::size_t) {
    return create(str);
}

Foo<wchar_t> operator"" _foo(const wchar_t *str, std::size_t) {
    return create(str);
}
```

It's a matter of an extra layer of indirection and that's all.
Obviously, it doesn't worth it if all your operators are one line body functions.

Comment: I guess that's clear enough. I wonder why they didn't allow this, though. Perhaps future standards will relax this proscription...

Comment: @Zorawar I'm just curious as you are, but I cannot figure out why it's not allowed. I'm sorry.

Comment: That's ok! Thanks for the answer. At least I know I haven't just made a stupid mistake!